# Entity from Optional Object (Java 8)

Tags: java, java-8, casting, option-type

I am having some issue while trying to pull an entity out of an ArrayList that holds and Optional. When I do a breakpoint I get the return below the code. I know I am close but lack the knowledge on how to pull the GrandClientDataCore@9463 out of the data being returned to me.

Edited to add the previous line before the for loop.

```
Error occured: java.util.Optional cannot be cast to net.glmhc.dmhwebservices.entities.GrandClientDataCores.
```

```
List<GrandClientDataCores> grandClientDataCoresList = getGrandClientDataCoreList(submitMode, grandClientDataCoreId);
for (GrandClientDataCores grandClientDataCores : grandClientDataCoresList) {
    CDCPAErrors request = new CDCPAErrors();
    request.setI(this.service.getRequestInfo(grandClientDataCores, submitMode, staff));
    logToFile(outDir, String.format("req_%s.xml", new Object[] {grandClientDataCores}), request);
    
    CDCPAErrorsResponse response = (CDCPAErrorsResponse) 
    getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(getWebServiceUri(), request, 
    (WebServiceMessageCallback) new SoapActionCallback("http://tempuri.org/CDCPAErrors"));

    logToFile(outDir, String.format("res_%s.xml", new Object[] {grandClientDataCoreId}), response);
    DmhServicesCdcResponse responseObj = getResponse(submitMode, response);
    this.service.saveResponse(grandClientDataCores, submitMode, responseObj, staff);
    responses.add(responseObj);
}
```

This is the getGrandClientDataCoreList

```
 protected List<GrandClientDataCores> getGrandClientDataCoreList(SubmitMode submitMode, String grandClientDataCore) throws Exception {
        List<GrandClientDataCores> grandClientDataCoresList;
        try {
            grandClientDataCoresList = (List<GrandClientDataCores>) this.service.getGrandClientDataCoreList(submitMode, grandClientDataCore);
         } catch ( Exception ex) {
             throw new Exception(ex);
         }

         if (grandClientDataCore == null || grandClientDataCore.isEmpty()) {
             throw new NoDataException("No CDC record to validate.");

         }
        return grandClientDataCoresList;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: List<GrandClientDataCores>

Comment: My guess is that this is because it is further wrapped by spring boot JPA which makes any findbyid into an Optional. I'll add more code to my original question.

Comment: @Noobiedamus What's the return type of `this.service.getGrandClientDataCoreList` ?

Comment: Object getGrandClientDataCoreList (SubmitMode paraSubmitMode, String paramString) throws Exception; @ETO from the interface of the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invoke `get()` on the optional to retrieve its value.  You cannot just cast `Optional<T>` to something else.  According to the debug image, the declaration of `grandClientDataCoresList` looked like this:

```
List<Optional<GrandClientDataCores>> grandClientDataCoresList ...
```

Therefore you need something like this:

```
for (Optional<GrandClientDataCores> gcdcOpt: grandClientDataCoresList) {
    GrandClientDataCores gcdc = gcdcOpt.get();
    ....
```

values in `grandClientDataCores` are of type `Optional<GrandClientDataCores>`.

Your actual error is here:

```
   protected List<GrandClientDataCores> getGrandClientDataCoreList(SubmitMode submitMode, String grandClientDataCore) throws Exception {
        List<GrandClientDataCores> grandClientDataCoresList;
        try {
            grandClientDataCoresList = (List<GrandClientDataCores>) this.service.getGrandClientDataCoreList(submitMode, grandClientDataCore);
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                       This cast is invalid
                                       
         } catch ( Exception ex) {
             throw new Exception(ex);
         }

         if (grandClientDataCore == null || grandClientDataCore.isEmpty()) {
             throw new NoDataException("No CDC record to validate.");

         }
        return grandClientDataCoresList;
    }
```

You will find that the actual type returned by `this.service.getGrandClientDataCoreList` is `List<Optional<GrandClientDataCores>>` so you must update your code accordingly, in a number of places.  For starters...

```
   protected List<Optional<GrandClientDataCores>> getGrandClientDataCoreList(SubmitMode submitMode, String grandClientDataCore) throws Exception {
        List<Optional<GrandClientDataCores>> grandClientDataCoresList;
        try {
            grandClientDataCoresList = this.service.getGrandClientDataCoreList(submitMode, grandClientDataCore);
         } catch ( Exception ex) {
             throw new Exception(ex);
         }

         if (grandClientDataCore == null || grandClientDataCore.isEmpty()) {
             throw new NoDataException("No CDC record to validate.");

         }
        return grandClientDataCoresList;
    }
```

and everywhere that you invoke this method.

Comment: When I try this ```for (GrandClientDataCores grandClientDataCores : grandClientDataCoresList.get()) {``` it asks me for an int. If I put an int just for Ss&Gs I get ```foreach not applicable to type 'net.glmhc.dmhwebservices.entities.GrandClientDataCores'```

Comment: That's not where the `get()` goes.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Jim I tried your updated answer but it gets me this error. Notice I did update my original question above perhaps that is why?

`
Required type:
GrandClientDataCores

Provided:
Optional
<net.glmhc.dmhwebservices.entities.GrandClientDataCores>
`

Comment: _"but it gets me this error"_ -- WHICH error? According to the image you posted, `grandClientDataCoresList` is definitely `List<Optional<GrandClientDataCores>>`. Something is inconsistent between the debug image and your question.

Comment: Required type: GrandClientDataCores Provided: Optional <net.glmhc.dmhwebservices.entities.GrandClientDataCores> is the error tried to format it at the end of my answer my apologies. This is likely and IDE warning more than an error.

Comment: Exactly. It's telling you that you declared it as `GrandClientDataCores` but you are actually attempting to assign an `Optional<GrandClientDataCores>`.  You need to examine what `this.service.getGrandClientDataCoreList()` ***actually*** returns.  You casted it to `List<GrandClientDataCores>` but that was an invalid cast which is not detected until runtime.

Comment: You are likely right. I am not arguing with you. I just lack the knowledge to find the issue. When I try applying the casting you mentioned (List<Optional<GrandClientDataCores>> grandClientDataCoresList = getGrandClientDataCoreList(submitMode, grandClientDataCoreId);) the IDE says the message below.

`Required type: List <Optional<GrandClientDataCores>>`

`Provided: List <GrandClientDataCores>`

Comment: The Optional is added for me automatically by the framework because I am using a built in framework function. I guess I will have to review deeper as probably a lot of my types are wrong then as a lot breaks when I try to make changes.

Comment: Yes, you need to understand what your framework does to your data before you can use it.

Comment: Had to refactor several type casts but this was the issue over all. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

use the "[get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--)" function of Optional, which will retrieve the object itself.
pay attention it will throw an exception if no object was populated into this Optional.

Comment: When I try this ```for (GrandClientDataCores grandClientDataCores : grandClientDataCoresList.get()) {``` it asks me for an int. If I put an int just for Ss&Gs I get ```foreach not applicable to type 'net.glmhc.dmhwebservices.entities.GrandClientDataCores'```

Answer (score 0):

GrandClientDataCores values in List are wrapped with Optional, so you have to check if value present:

```java
grandClientDataCores.isPresent()
```

and if it is then just get it:

```java
grandClientDataCores.get();
```

Alternatively, you can do something like that:

```java
grandClientDataCores.orElse(new GrandClientDataCores())
```

And I recommend to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)